# NoMethodError in ConnectionController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I access localhost:3000,
my browser told error of  NoMethodError in ConnectionController#index.
Also,I was told that undefined method `action' for ConnectionController(Table doesn't exist):Class.

The error browser told connection_controller.rb of 26 line was wrong but I didn't write codes so long like 26 lines.

```css
 send(name, *arguments, &block)
      else
        super
      end
    end
```

I wrote ,in connection_controller.rb

```css
class ConnectionController <  ActiveRecord::Base
    def index
        personal = {'name'=>'Yamada','old'=>28}
        render :json => personal

    end
end
```

in routes.rb,

```css
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  namespace :connection do
      get '/',action:'index'
    end
end
```

in schema.rb

```css
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170101073143) do

  create_table "userdata", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

in migrate file ,

```css
class CreateUserdata < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :userdata do |t|
     t.string :name
      t.text :image
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

in model,

```css
class Userdatum < ActiveRecord::Base
 user = User.new
 user.name = "XXX"
 user.email = "mail"
 user.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that a controller in Rails should extend `ActionController` class and a Model should extend `ActiveRecord::Base` class.

You seems to have done this

```
class ConnectionController < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

inside your controller.

It should be

```
class ConnectionController <  ApplicationController
end
```